# C# Is it possible to do yield return without memory allocation?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, yield-return

Assuming we have a specific scenario, where we want to have zero memory allocations. Is it somehow possible to use yield return (without memory allocation)?

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetValues()
{
    yield return 42;
}
```

For example, I can make a struct with GetEnumerator returning struct and use it in foreach to avoid memory allocation:

> (it’s possible because foreach loop actually does not use any
> interface constraint on the loop source. You can create a class which
> would work with foreach without implementing neither IEnumerable nor
> IEnumerable – but that’s a topic for another blog post)
> https://marcinjuraszek.com/2013/10/playing-around-with-listt-part-two-ienumerable-and-ienumerablet-implementation.html

Is it somehow also possible with yield return?

Comment: `yield return` will always generate a class under the hood. You have to do it manually through struct.

Comment: yield return does _not_ allocate. The call to GetValues() does allocate a new compiler generated IEnumerable object. So if you can cache that, you're fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems no, while for `foreach` specification [explicitly mentions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#1395-the-foreach-statement) ability to use duck-typing with special type(s):

> - Otherwise, determine whether the type `X` has an appropriate `GetEnumerator` method:
>   ....

So you can do some magic for allocation-free `foreach`.

The `yeild return` [specifically requires](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#1315-the-yield-statement) specific return type:

> The `yield` statement is used in an iterator block (§13.3) to yield a value to the enumerator object ([§15.14.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#15145-enumerator-objects)) or enumerable object ([§15.14.6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#15146-enumerable-objects)) of an iterator or to signal the end of the iterator

And the actual implementation is handled by the compiler (and currently is a reference type,.so it will allocate) and AFAIK there is no way currently to intercept/substitute it.